# Find a unit tangent vector to a curve that is an intersection of two surfaces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The intersection of the two surfaces given by the Cartesian equations $2x^2+3y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$ contains a curve $C$ passing through the point $P=(\sqrt{7},3,4)$. These equations may be solved for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ to give a parametric representation of $C$ with $z$ as a parameter.

(a) Find a unit tangent vector $T$ to $C$ at the point $P$ without using an explicit knowledge of the parametric representation.

(b) Check the result in part (a) by determining a parametric representation of $C$ with $z$ as a parameter.

For (b), I solved the two equations for the surfaces given to get $y^2=25-z^2$ and $x^2=2z^2-25$. Since we're looking for the curve that contains $P$, $x$, $y$ should be positive so we get $y=\sqrt{25-z^2}$ and $x=\sqrt{2z^2-25}$. So from this I get the parametric representation $(\sqrt{2z^2-25}, \sqrt{25-z^2},z)$ for the curve $C$.

Is this the correct way of finding the parametrization? Moreover, I do not know how to find the unit targent vector $T$ to $C$ at $P$, without getting a parametrization. How can I find this? The answer to $T$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{751}}(24,-4\sqrt{7},3\sqrt{7})$.

I would greatly appreciate any solutions, hints or suggestions.

Comment: You can calculate the vecors normal to the surfaces at point $P$. The tangent $T$ that you re looking for is perpendicular to these 2 vectors, so you  can calculate T.

Comment: Thanks. But is my parametrization correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint a:**

The normal to $2x^2+3y^2-z^2=25$ at $(\sqrt7,3,4)$ is parallel to the gradient: $(4x,6y,-2z)=2(2\sqrt7,9,-4)$

The normal to $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$ at $(\sqrt7,3,4)$ is parallel  to the gradient: $(2x,2y,-2z)=2(\sqrt7,3,-4)$

The common tangent to both surfaces would be perpendicular to both of these normals, which would make it parallel to their cross product
$$
(2\sqrt7,9,-4)\times(\sqrt7,3,-4)=(-24,4\sqrt7,-3\sqrt7)
$$

---

**Hint b:**

We are given that $2x^2+3y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$. Therefore, by subtracting the equations, we have that
$$
x^2+2y^2=25
$$
which can be parametrized by $(x,y)=\left(5\cos(\theta),\frac5{\sqrt2}\sin(\theta)\right)$. For each point $(x,y)$, the $z$ coordinate can be computed from the equation from either surface.

Comment: Why is the normal parallel to the gradient?

Comment: The chain rule says $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} $$ The curve we are considering is $f(x,y)=0$, so along that curve we have $$ \begin{align} 0 &=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}\\ &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\\ &=\nabla f\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{x}}{\mathrm{d}t} \end{align} $$

Comment: That is, the gradient of $f$ is perpendicular to the curve. The normal is perpendicular to the curve. Thus, the gradient is parallel to the normal.

Answer (score 0):

For $(b)$, by
$$
\begin{cases}
2x^2+3y^2-z^2=25 \\
x^2+y^2=z^2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
and working on the first:
$$\underbrace{2x^2+2y^2}_{2 z^2}+y^2-z^2=25\ \Rightarrow \ z^2+y^2=25$$
Then the curve is a circumference in the y-z plane and its parametric representation is:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=5 \cos t \\
y=5 \sin t \\
\end{cases}
$$
for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.